# Rate Limiter on spring integration

Tags: spring-integration, throttling

We are analyzing to upgrade from spring integration 4.3 to 5.x to use the upcoming RateLimiterRequestHandlerAdvice in a flow with an http outbound gateway with dynamic url, but could not found an example in the docs, is this possible?

```
 <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="request"
        reply-channel="response" url-expression="headers.serviceUrl" 
        http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8"/>
```

I saw the examples (https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RC1/reference/html/handler-advice.html#rate-limiter-advice) but they were for only for a service activator which does not have this dynamic behaviour.

We need a rate limiter for each url. For example, for url1 is 10 tps and for url2 is 20 tps. Also, it would be usefull if it can be changed on runtime.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be used with any `MessageHandler`. When using XML configuration, use the `<request-handler-advice-chain/>` child element.

See [Adding Behavior to Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#message-handler-advice-chain).

Comment: I found that but can I add different Rate Limit for each url?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. No; it has no capability to change the rate for each URL, the state is applied to the message handler as a whole. You would need to use a router and multiple gateways instead.